# OpenAPI Reference to multiple verbs under one endpoint

Tags: yaml, openapi, endpoint

I'm taking the create your API docs approach before writing my code and I'm quite new to the OpenAPI specs.

This is a part of my `openapi.yaml` file:

```
paths:
  /player/{playerId}:
    get:
      $ref: paths/player/get.yaml
    put:
      $ref: paths/player/put.yaml
    patch:
      $ref: paths/player/patch.yaml
```

This would totally make sense for me but for some reason, it's not supported? I'd like to keep my verbs in separate files. Does anyone have any suggestions? Cheers for the help!

Comment: What makes you think this isn't supported? Please supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe the problem you encounter. From what you're showing, it is not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. `$ref` is only supported where the specification explicitly mentions support for $ref.

In your case, https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#operationObject is the interesting object. It does not list $ref, so, unfortunately it is not supported.

What you can do is a `$ref` at the path level (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#pathItemObject):

This would look like this:

```yaml
paths:
  /player/{playerId}:
    $ref: paths/player/playerId.yaml
```

with `playerId.yaml` like this:

```yaml
get:
  # content of paths/player/get.yaml

put:
  # content of paths/player/put.yaml
 
patch:
  # content of paths/player/patch.yaml
```

Comment: Ah, I see, gotcha! Thanks for the explanation :) However, I would be much happier with my version as it looks cleaner to me but this is my own opinion.